# How do I iterate through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, ascii, clock

I need to take an inputted time, for example "12:20", and print a 5x3 ASCII clock representation of it. But I don't know how how iterate through a list of dictionaries, which I think is the simplest way to solve this problem.

```py
time = input("enter a time HH:MM")
my_list = [
{"0": "000", "1": " 1 ","2":"222","3":"333","4":"44","5":"555","6":"666","7":"777","8":"888","9":"999"},
{"0": "000", "1": "11 ", "2": "  2", "3":"  3","4":"4 4","5":"5  ","6":"6  ","7":"  7","8":"8 8","9":"9 9"},
{"0": "000", "1": " 1 ", "2": "222", "3":"333","4":"444","5":"555","6":"666","7":"  7","8":"888","9":"999"},
{"0": "000", "1": " 1 ", "2": "2  ", "3":"  3","4":"  4","5":"  5","6":"6 6","7":"  7","8":"8 8","9":"  9"},
{"0": "000", "1": "111", "2": "222", "3":"333","4":"  4","5":"555","6":"666","7":"  7","8":"888","9":"  9"}
]
for i in my_list:
    for l in my_list.keys():
        if l == time[i]:
            print(my_list[i][l])
```

I tried making a list of dictionaries with two `for` loops: one for iterating through the list and one for iterating through each dictionary. If the input is 12:20, I need to print a 5x3 12:00 like so:

```
 1    222    222  000
11      2  :   2  0 0
 1    222    222  0 0
 1    2    : 2    0 0 
111   222    222  000
```

Comment: `for l in my_list.keys():` , do you mean `for l in i.keys():` ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a check that the time input is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You just overlooked a few fundamentals. Such as: you have to get the entire line before you print it, names matter, and you can't print a colon if you don't include one in your segments.

```
import re

time_valid = re.compile(r'^\d{2}:\d{2}$')

while not time_valid.match((time := input("enter a time HH:MM: "))):
    #keep asking this question til the user get's it right
    pass
    
segments = [
{"0":"000", "1":" 1 ", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"4 4", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"777", "8":"888", "9":"999", ":":" "},
{"0":"0 0", "1":"11 ", "2":"  2", "3":"  3", "4":"4 4", "5":"5  ", "6":"6  ", "7":"  7", "8":"8 8", "9":"9 9", ":":":"},
{"0":"0 0", "1":" 1 ", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"444", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"  7", "8":"888", "9":"999", ":":" "},
{"0":"0 0", "1":" 1 ", "2":"2  ", "3":"  3", "4":"  4", "5":"  5", "6":"6 6", "7":"  7", "8":"8 8", "9":"  9", ":":":"},
{"0":"000", "1":"111", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"  4", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"  7", "8":"888", "9":"  9", ":":" "}
]

for segment in segments:
    line = ''
    for c in time: #gather the entire line before printing
        line = f'{line} {segment[c]}'
    print(line)
```

With very little work this can be made into a console clock.

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from os       import system, name

#repeating timer
class Poll(threading.Timer):  
    def run(self):  
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):  
            self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs) 
            
segments = [
{"0":"000", "1":" 1 ", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"4 4", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"777", "8":"888", "9":"999", ":":" "},
{"0":"0 0", "1":"11 ", "2":"  2", "3":"  3", "4":"4 4", "5":"5  ", "6":"6  ", "7":"  7", "8":"8 8", "9":"9 9", ":":":"},
{"0":"0 0", "1":" 1 ", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"444", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"  7", "8":"888", "9":"999", ":":" "},
{"0":"0 0", "1":" 1 ", "2":"2  ", "3":"  3", "4":"  4", "5":"  5", "6":"6 6", "7":"  7", "8":"8 8", "9":"  9", ":":":"},
{"0":"000", "1":"111", "2":"222", "3":"333", "4":"  4", "5":"555", "6":"666", "7":"  7", "8":"888", "9":"  9", ":":" "}
]

def display():
    #get time
    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    #clear console
    system(('clear','cls')[name=='nt'])

    #draw console
    for segment in segments:
        line = ''
        for c in time: 
            #illustrates a simple method to replace graphics
            line = f'{line} {segment[c].replace(c,chr(9608))}'
        print(line)

#start clock    
Poll(.1, display).start()
```